# Comparing semver versions with tilde / caret

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

Say I am using the NPM semver package:

```
const semver = require('semver');
```

if I am comparing an exact version with tilde/caret version, does it matter which argument has the tilde/caret? For example:

```
semver.eq('1.2.3', '^1.2');
```

or

```
semver.neq('~1.3.3', '1.2.8');
```

I am guessing that you can switch the arguments without any change, but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `semver.eq` does not work with ranges like that.

`semver.satisfies` does and there the position matters:

```
console.log(semver.satisfies('1.0.0', '^1'))     // true
console.log(semver.satisfies('1.2.2', '~1.2.3')) // false


console.log(semver.satisfies('^1.0', '1.0.0'))   // Exception
console.log(semver.satisfies('1.2.2', '~1.2.3')) // Exception

console.log(semver.eq('1.0.0', '^1.0.0'))        // Exception
console.log(semver.eq('^1.0', '1.2.3'))          // Exception
```

Here is a `ripl` [link to see](https://repl.it/@akrion/semverTests)

Comment: thanks, yeah I figures my guess was wrong, much appreciated.

Comment: if there is a 'not satisfies' or do we use the ! operator?

Comment: Something like this passed: `console.log(semver.satisfies('1.2.3', '1.x || >=2.5.0 && !(5.0.0 - 7.2.3)'))`